# How to keep selected tab on page refresh with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu with a "nav-tabs" class property as follows. What I want is to keep the last active tab active again when the page is refreshed. There are dozens of solutions on the Internet, but none of them have worked. Is there anyone who can help with this?
Regards.

My tabs are here
[Tabs Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzyIn.png)

JS codes are here
[JS Cdes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEem8.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.